# Table View Cell - Auto-Layout Constraints ambiguity

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to create a custom table view cell and which consists of one image view and three labels.

Here's a screenshot of the same:

[image]

These are my constraints:

[image]

I get the following errors in the console:

[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c4090a40 'Bottom' V:[UILabel:0x103e0b220'Snacks']-(15)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x103e097d0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c4090040 'CategoryLabelHeight' UILabel:0x103e0b220'Snacks'.height == 20   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c40909a0 'CategoryLabelTop' V:[UILabel:0x103e0ad40'Frito Lay']-(0)-[UILabel:0x103e0b220'Snacks']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c408fcd0 'MakerLabelHeight' UILabel:0x103e0ad40'Frito Lay'.height == 25   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c4090950 'MakerLabelTop' V:[UILabel:0x103e0aa60'Lays Potato Chips, Classi...']-(0)-[UILabel:0x103e0ad40'Frito Lay']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c408fc30 'NameLabelHeight' UILabel:0x103e0aa60'Lays Potato Chips, Classi...'.height == 30   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c40906d0 'NameLabelTop' V:|-(15)-[UILabel:0x103e0aa60'Lays Potato Chips, Classi...']   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x103e097d0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c8091cb0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x103e097d0.height == 105   (active)>"
```

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint:

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c408fc30 'NameLabelHeight' UILabel:0x103e0aa60'Lays Potato Chips, Classi...'.height == 30   (active)>
```

I also get the following errors in Xcode:

[image]

1. I tried to read online about UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height, but I couldn't find anything concrete. Any pointers on that?
2. The constraints mentioned under missing constraints have been implemented. Why does it still say so?
3. Does the value of estimatedRowHeight affect anything?

What am I missing out on?

Comment: In the last image of yours..there is a red dot in the right side. Click on it. It will give you a popup with a add missing constraints button.click on it. after that save and run your app.

Comment: Why would you set height for label? Upload your storyboard/xib file here would make it easier to debug

Comment: @Tj3n Because I'd like their height to be fixed. I didn't understand what you meant by upload your file?

Comment: Upload your storyboard/xib that contains your cell to any fileuploader and post the link here, it would be easier to see what's wrong